# ¿Cómo actualizo una variable desde un componente a medida que se llama en diferentes vistas?

Tags: vue.js

He hecho un componente muy simple en Vue que hace de Breadcrumb (las "miguitas de pan" que indican la routa donde se está):

```
<template>
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">{{ section }}</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" v-if="subsection.length" aria-current="page">{{ subsection }}</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Breadcrumb",
        props: {
            section: {},
            subsection: {
                default: ""
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Con ella indico el primer nivel de la web y, opcionalmente, segunda. Así pongo esto (cada uno en una vista diferente):

```
<Breadcrumb section="Sección1" subsection="Subsección1" />
<Breadcrumb section="Sección2" />
```

Y se muestre así, respectivamente:

```
Sección1 / subsección1
Sección2
```

Sin embargo, es algo pesado tener que poner siempre los parámetros cuando es algo que ya está definido en la URL: `<mi_dominio>/seccion1/subseccion1` vs `<mi_dominio>/seccion2/`. ¿Existe alguna manera de modificar esta propiedad a medida que la URL cambia? Leí sobre [`watch()` y `computed()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) y combinarlos con `this.$router.currentPath` pero no sé si son apropiados para este caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que la lógica que le aplicas al componente está bien si solo vas tener un bajo nivel de profundidad pero realmente no es confiable cuando la profundidad de las paginas aumentan y la cosa se complica ya que no es una solución escalable.

Aunque existen varias maneras de hacer esto; como en tu ejemplo, si estas utilizando el router lo mas adecuado es hacerlo con este ya que no es nada del otro mundo, a menos que tu paginación no dependa estrictamente de las rutas de tu app, por lo que te recomendaría hacerlo con vuex almacenando las rutas manualmente a través de algún sistema de referencias de padres e hijos, en ese caso claro.

Lo mas lógico de un componente tan re-utilizable es que sea dinámico escalable, por lo tanto mas fácil de usar, así que en el ejemplo trabajaremos con el router como antes ya mencionado.

---

**Para empezar** escribimos un método para obtener nuestras rutas y procesarlas para devolver los valores deseados.

Podemos obtener nuestra ruta actual desde cualquier parte de nuestro componente simplemente utilizando `this.$route` con el que obtendremos el path, **mira como podemos utilizarlo**:

```
// Breadcrumb.vue
{
  ...,
  methods:{
    getPaths() {
      var route = this.$route,
      path = route.path // Obtenemos la ruta absoluta de la pagina actual
      Foo...
    } 
  },
  ...
}
```

[Ver mas sobre $route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript)

**Ahora hay un par de problemas**, bien sabemos que obtenemos el path absoluto cuando estamos en una ruta especifica (que es lo único que nos da el objeto `this.$route`) y puede ser así por ejemplo `/home/ajax`, podría ponérselo a la migaja (el botón o link) que le corresponde, pero la migaja consecutiva anterior no puede llevar la misma ruta porque nos redireccionaría a la misma pagina, quiero decir, por lo que simplemente no podemos poner la ruta tal cual en un botón ni tampoco crear mil botones con la misma ruta (evidentemente) hay que crear un botón para la ruta `/home/ajax`, otro para `/home` e incluso otro para `/`.

**Por lo que la solución mas lógica es**:

1. Tomar el string de la ruta y aplicarle un split para obtener un array con todos los steps de la ruta:

   ```
   var path = "/home/ajax",
   deep = path.split("/"); // ===> ["","home","ajax"]
   ```
2. Mapear el array para retornar cada paso por separado, en este caso retorne un objeto con la ruta de cada migaja pero también el nombre del paso para poder usarla en la interfaz:

   ```
   let last = "";

   deep.map(c => {
     last = c.length > 0 ? last + "/" + c : ""; //Verifico si el item tiene contenido y aplico la concatenación para poder reconstruir el path paso a paso.
     return c.length > 0 ? { path: last, nick: c } : { path: "/", nick: "root" }; // retorno un objeto que contine el path de la migaja y el nombre.
   });
   ```

   > **NOTA**: La variable last esta fuera del map para ir acumulando la concatenación de la ruta.

   **Ahora tenemos un array parecido  esto:**:

   ```
   [{ path: "/", nick: "root" },{ path: "/home", nick: "home" },{ path: "/home/ajax", nick: "ajax" }]`
   ```
3. Introducimos el array en la data (ej.; `this.deep = deep`) y el método está listo.

---

Ahora solo falta invocar el método en el hook `mounted()` del componente para ejecutarlo al momento de montarse el cimponente y también declaramos el event listener `this.$router.afterEach()` que es el hook de entrada de cada pagina en el router cuando esté cambia, que se obtiene a través del mismo objeto `$router` por lo que no tienes que utilizar watchers, luego dentro de este también invocar el metodo (`this.getPaths()`) para que se llame tambien cada vez que la ruta cambie.

```
{
  ...,
  mounted() {
    this.setPaths();
    this.$router.afterEach(() => {
      this.setPaths();
    });
  },
  ...
}
```

Ver mas sobre [Ciclo de vida de Vue](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Diagrama-del-Ciclo-de-vida) y [router Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#navigation-guards)

**Ahora creamos el template del componente y hemos terminado**:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(route, i) in deep" :key="i">
      <router-link :to="route.path">/{{route.nick}}</router-link>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

> Como ves estamos loopeando y accediendo al path y al nombre para usarlos en nuestro link como queramos.

**Dando como resultado**:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <a href="/">/root</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="/home">/home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="/home/ajax">/ajax</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Si no hubiesemos creado el alias o nombre en el objeto y simplemente agregasemos el path como si fuera el nombre en los li, **en la vista habría algo como**:

```
// Ruta del ejemplo

--------------------------
|    //home/home/ajax    |
--------------------------

// Ruta mas profunda

----------------------------------------------
|    //home/home/ajax/home/ajax/otra_ruta    |
----------------------------------------------
```

**Cuando lo correcto seria simplemente**:

```
// Ruta del ejemplo

--------------------
|    /home/ajax    |
--------------------

// Ruta mas profunda

------------------------------
|    /home/ajax/otra_ruta    |
------------------------------
```

Ya con el resultado esperado lo implementamos en cualquier parte de nuestra app como cualquier componente y todo en orden.

**Observa el código a detalle** (asegúrate de entrar a rutas inexistentes, igual se actualizara el componente, no hay pagina de error 404):

[image: Edit lucid-varahamihira-glxyy]

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Qué buenísima respuesta, muchas gracias por detallarla tan bien que incluso un principiante como yo la seguí perfectamente. Añadí alguna cosilla, como `deep.shift();` para quitar el elemento raíz y también usé `<ol class="breadcrumb">` y `<li class="breadcrumb-item"
                    v-for="route in deep"
                    :key="route.name"
            >` para que Bootstrap haga su magia y quede bien formateado.

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que te sirvió! dejé la raiz por si necesitabas acceder a este también desde los breadcrumbs pero está execelente, y lo de boostrap muy buena idea, un saludo.